# Get headers with an underscore on NGINX

Tags: php, nginx, php-5.5

I have multiple apps in Google Play and App Store. These send custom request headers but these headers include an underscore e.g `api_key`.

The server has now moved from PHP 5.2 on Apache to PHP 5.5 on nginx. On NGINX, `apache_request_headers()` and `getallheaders()` are not available.

Is there any way to read custom request headers on NGINX server without having to go and update all apps to remove the underscore? Parsing the `$_SERVER` variable does not work either - any headers  using and underscore are dropped.

Comment: Have you dumped the `$_SERVER` variable? Are the parameters in there with `HTTP_` prefixed? http://serverfault.com/a/258940

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to set `underscores_in_headers on` in [your NGINX config](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#underscores_in_headers).

Comment: which file? nginx 1.10.2, ubuntu 14.04

Comment: TechyTimo - it can be set in http or server blocks, so typically that's nginx.conf or your vhost file (e.g in /sites_available)

Comment: Be warned that ```If the directive is specified on the server level, its value is only used if a server is a default one.``` (from http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#underscores_in_headers)