# NGINX location prefix support underscore?

Tags: nginx

I am using NGINX version 1.19.10 on docker environment.

when I have below `location` prefix; I can access TXT file successfully via http://example.com/abs.txt

```
location /abs\.txt {
            alias /usr/abs.txt }
```

when I include `underscore` in `location` prefix; I failed to access TXT file via http://example.com/abs_support_AB58gLoD.txt end up with error `404 NOT Found`.

```
location /abs_support_AB58gLoD\.txt {
            alias /usr/abs.txt }
```

Within the same NGINX config file, exactly the same `location` prefix (with `underscore`) setup in another `server` directive with different FQDN , worked perfectly.

I am completely lost and could not find out why. I follow docs to enable access log / error log, but it is completely empty in the file.

**--Add Troubleshooting Output--**
I change `location` prefix to below, I can access http://example.com/abs_support_AB58gLo.txt successfully. but when I append the last `D` to the filename, [http://example.com/abs_support_AB58gLoD\.txt](http://example.com/abs_support_AB58gLoD%5C.txt), I failed with `500 Internal Error`.

```
location ~ /MP.*\.txt {}
```

I tried `underscores_in_headers on;` as well, problem persisted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get headers with an underscore on NGINX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26938604/get-headers-with-an-underscore-on-nginx)

Comment: I tried, but problem persisted.